# How to create a circular multi-histogram graph using the R package circlize?

Tags: r, data-visualization, circlize, circos, data-presentation

I apologize in advance since I am a beginner user in R.

I have a big data file, with multiple factors (15), and multiple tested samples from various group within each factor (5). I have calculated the means for each group within each factor. To simplify the presentation of my data, I would like to create a circular plot to present this information. I came upon the package 'circilize' and the 'circos.trackHist()' is a perfect choice for my purposes. Unfortunately, the guide I am looking at does not provide an example of how to use imported data, but rather creates simulated data from scratch. In addition, it is rather complex for my level and I would appreciate any support with graphing it. If I have the following data in tabular form in excel, how could I create a circular plot?

`║ Factor   ║ group   ║ average ║
 ║ Factor1  ║ A       ║ 77.53   ║
 ║ Factor1  ║ B       ║ 54.98   ║
 ║ Factor1  ║ B       ║ 43.35   ║
 ║ Factor1  ║ C       ║ 243.0   ║
 ║ Factor2  ║ A       ║ 91.3    ║
 ║ Factor2  ║ A       ║ 70.2    ║
 ║ Factor2  ║ A       ║ 67.93   ║
 ║ Factor3  ║ C       ║ 16.49   ║
 ║ Factor3  ║ B       ║ 0       ║
 ║ Factor3  ║ C       ║ 5.1416  ║`

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you need to create a matrix. Use the factors as your rows and groups as your columns and write a loop to load the values into the matrix. Might have to do it in data frame and convert to matrix, but it shouldn't be too hard.